# On-time production rate SSRS Report error

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to run the default SSRS report called: On-time production rate from Production control, I am using AX2012 R3.

Running the report gives me the error: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` all other SSRS reports in my enviroment are working.

This problem exists in our own enviroment, as well in our default Contoso enviroment. No modifications to the report has been made.

I have tried deploying the report, the SSRS report and the Visual Studio both exists in the AOT.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your AOS can't connect to the SRS for some reason. Permissions or configuration. There's a lot to check here, but not really programming related unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexKwitny Strange though that it only occurs for one report. I would think that a permission or configuration issue would impact all reports?

Comment: It could be a non-AX SSRS report? I've seen that error too many times though. The report settings in AX could point to multiple SSRS servers. The Report Server Configuration Settings may the wrong users. It could be the Business Connector user in AX config. It could be the *.axc file located in the report server config. It could be bad WCF data in the AXC file. The permissions set in SSRS. Even firewall. For it to be one report, I find that especially unusual, but when I say "configuration" I mean it could be a ton of settings. I think the error is real in that whatever machine is refusing it.